# AspnetCore 2.1 custom Authorisation filter issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have an Asp.net core 2 Web api. and I'm trying to implement a custom authorisation filter.

At the moment I have the following:

```
 public class AuthorisationAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorisationAttribute() : base(typeof(AuthorisationFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, "will be my user data") };
    }
}
 public class AuthorisationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
    public AuthorisationFilter(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var authorisationCookie = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Where(t => t.Key == "auth").FirstOrDefault();

        var temp = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var unencryptedToken = temp.ReadToken(authorisationCookie.Value) as JwtSecurityToken;

        var session = _httpContext.Session;
        //MORE TO DO HERE YET! Just want to test getting called when expected. 
        return;
    }
}
```

Then on a controller method I Have:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorisation(),HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
          return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

When I run the application The authorisationAttribute constructor gets called. At the point I try to call the controller Method I receive the following Error:

> InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type
>   AuthorisationFilter; could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete
>   and services are registered for all parameters of a public
>   constructor.

So in my startup.cs file I also added:

`services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationFilter, AuthorisationFilter>();`

but it's made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in DI does not know anything about the current `HttpContext`, first you have to add the `IHttpContextAccessor` to the service collection:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then you can get it as your filters constructor argument:

```
public AuthorisationFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Then you can access to the current `HttpContext` via `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext`.

However you can also access the current `HttpContext` through your `AuthorizationFilterContext` like you already use that in your sample code:

```
context.HttpContext
```

**Edit**: As you are setting the `Argument` property of the `TypeFilterAttribute` you have to make a constructor in your filter that uses that argument, so like:

```
public AuthorisationFilter(Claim claim)
{
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I still receive the exact same error. I tried removing the input parameter all together on the authorisationFilter constructor, effectively making it an empty constructor for now just to see if it get's in there and this still gave the same error

Comment: Updated my answer, i didn't noticed that you are setting the `Argument` prop of the `TypeFilterAttribute` sry

Comment: Thank you....I have other issues, but I now get the onAuthorization method firing. So I'll try and deal with those else raise a fresh post.